# Beautifulsoup Scrapping Table with Pagination

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape this site URL: https://statusinvest.com.br/fundos-imobiliarios/urpr11 to get from a table the dividends info from this specific REIT (I'll later generalize this). This is the table that contains the info:

[dividends table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBSjy.png)

I was able to get the dates and values from the table, but only for the first page. When I change the table page there's no modification in the website URL so I actually don't know how to deal with this. Any help would be appreciated.

**Obs:** It would be nice if the way to solve doesn't depende on the amount of pages because some REITs can have more than 2 pages of info.

This is how I'm currently taking the info from the first page

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


URL = "https://statusinvest.com.br/fundos-imobiliarios/urpr11"
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
test = soup.find_all("tr", class_="")

rows = []
for r in test:
  if not r.find("td", title="Rendimento"):
    continue
  row = []
  for child in r.findChildren():
    if child.text.lower()=="rendimento":
      continue
    print(child.text)
    row.append(child.text)
  rows.append(row)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content is provided dynamically by `JavaScript`, what `requests` per se is not rendering, so you wont get all the data that way.

###### How to fix?

You could use `selenium` to interact with the website like humans would do it in the browser - Something for later and more complicated issues.

But in this case it is much more simple and do not need `selenium`. Just grab the `JSON` data `JavaScript` is using to provide the table:

```
data = json.loads(soup.select_one('#results')['value'])
```

Convert it into `DataFrame` adjust for your needs and save it to csv,json, ....

```
pd.DataFrame(data).to_csv('yourFile.csv', index=False)
```

There are more columns as displayed on the website, take a look at the output of the example. These adjustments will give you the expected ones by only reading specific data and renaming column headers:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['et','ed', 'pd', 'v'])
df.columns = ['TIPO','DATA COM','PAGAMENTO','VALOR']
df.to_csv('yourFile.csv', index=False)
```

| TIPO | DATA COM | PAGAMENTO | VALOR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Rendimento | 25/02/2022 | 15/03/2022 | 1.635 |
| Rendimento | 31/01/2022 | 14/02/2022 | 1.63 |

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, json
import pandas as pd


URL = "https://statusinvest.com.br/fundos-imobiliarios/urpr11"
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

data = json.loads(soup.select_one('#results')['value'])
pd.DataFrame(data)

#or with adjustment as mentioned above
#df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['et','ed', 'pd', 'v'])
#df.columns = ['TIPO','DATA COM','PAGAMENTO','VALOR']
#df.to_csv('yourFile.csv', index=False)
```

##### Output

| y | m | d | ad | ed | pd | et | etd | v | ov | sv | sov | adj |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |  | 25/02/2022 | 15/03/2022 | Rendimento | Rendimento | 1.635 |  | 1,63500000 | - | False |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |  | 31/01/2022 | 14/02/2022 | Rendimento | Rendimento | 1.63 |  | 1,63000000 | - | False |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |  | 30/12/2021 | 14/01/2022 | Rendimento | Rendimento | 1.67 |  | 1,67000000 | - | False |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |  | 30/11/2021 | 14/12/2021 | Rendimento | Rendimento | 1.869 |  | 1,86900000 | - | False |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |  | 29/10/2021 | 16/11/2021 | Rendimento | Rendimento | 1.37 |  | 1,37000000 | - | False |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |  | 30/09/2021 | 15/10/2021 | Rendimento | Rendimento | 2.17 |  | 2,17000000 | - | False |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |  | 31/08/2021 | 15/09/2021 | Rendimento | Rendimento | 2.01 |  | 2,01000000 | - | False |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |  | 30/07/2021 | 13/08/2021 | Rendimento | Rendimento | 1.48 |  | 1,48000000 | - | False |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |  | 30/06/2021 | 14/07/2021 | Rendimento | Rendimento | 2.4 |  | 2,40000000 | - | False |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |  | 31/05/2021 | 15/06/2021 | Rendimento | Rendimento | 2.06 |  | 2,06000000 | - | False |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |  | 30/04/2021 | 14/05/2021 | Rendimento | Rendimento | 1.185 |  | 1,18500000 | - | False |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |  | 31/03/2021 | 15/04/2021 | Rendimento | Rendimento | 2.87 |  | 2,87000000 | - | False |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |  | 26/02/2021 | 12/03/2021 | Rendimento | Rendimento | 2.09 |  | 2,09000000 | - | False |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |  | 29/01/2021 | 12/02/2021 | Rendimento | Rendimento | 2.25 |  | 2,25000000 | - | False |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |  | 30/12/2020 | 15/01/2021 | Rendimento | Rendimento | 2.01 |  | 2,01000000 | - | False |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |  | 30/11/2020 | 14/12/2020 | Rendimento | Rendimento | 2.03668 |  | 2,03668260 | - | False |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |  | 30/10/2020 | 13/11/2020 | Rendimento | Rendimento | 3.24 |  | 3,24000000 | - | False |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |  | 30/09/2020 | 15/10/2020 | Rendimento | Rendimento | 2.15 |  | 2,15000000 | - | False |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |  | 31/08/2020 | 15/09/2020 | Rendimento | Rendimento | 1.35 |  | 1,35000000 | - | False |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |  | 31/07/2020 | 14/08/2020 | Rendimento | Rendimento | 0.814098 |  | 0,81409811 | - | False |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |  | 30/06/2020 | 15/07/2020 | Rendimento | Rendimento | 1.56063 |  | 1,56063128 | - | False |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |  | 29/05/2020 | 15/06/2020 | Rendimento | Rendimento | 0.778074 |  | 0,77807445 | - | False |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |  | 30/04/2020 | 11/05/2020 | Rendimento | Rendimento | 0.615445 |  | 0,61544523 | - | False |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |  | 14/04/2020 | 15/04/2020 | Rendimento | Rendimento | 0.189474 |  | 0,18947368 | - | False |

Comment: thanks for taking your time to help me out with this one!!! I don't understand a lot of the intricacies when I'm inspecting the page. I have just one quick question where did you find the results tag in the page to search for it?

Comment: Always and first at all take a look into your `soup` - If the element your searching for is not provided as expected, it mostly is generated by `JavaScript`. So watch out for xhr requests in your consol and/or search the `soup` for specific content - In this case I searched for one of the valors and this was stored in the tag with #results